# The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/servername.comp.local:server]

Tags: sql-server

after trying installing an ms sql express 2014

the log contains :

> The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the
> Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/domain.domain.local:servername ]
> for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0x200b, state: 15.
> Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use
> NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further
> action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by
> authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually
> registered.

on installtaion at stage (the installation fails and the service cannot be started)

> SqlEngineDbStartConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu64

this error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority
> that is not trusted.)
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
> this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2269.0&EvtType=0xBA6E21AA%25400x9A41B222
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### &Retry Cancel

the sql was installed with sql Authentication

installation failed log:

> Overall summary:   Final result:                  Failed: see details
> below   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551   Start time:
> 2021-06-27 11:38:28   End time:                      2021-06-27
> 11:52:38   Requested action:              Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
> information for those features:   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use
> the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this
> feature, and then run the setup process again.   Next step for
> Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error,
> uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  computer
> Machine processor count:       8   OS version:
> Windows Server 2012   OS service pack:                  OS region:
> United States   OS language:                   English (United States)
> OS architecture:               x64   Process architecture:          64
> Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
> Instance ID                    Feature
> Language             Edition              Version         Clustered
> Configured   SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER
> MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services
> 1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2269.0     No
> Yes          SQL Server 2014      MSSQLSERVER
> MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication
> 1033                 Express Edition      12.0.2269.0     No
> Yes          SQL Server 2014
> Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express
> Edition      12.0.2269.0     No         Yes          SQL Server 2014
> Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Express
> Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes          SQL Server 2014
> Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Express
> Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes          SQL Server 2014
> Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Express
> Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes          SQL Server 2014
> Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Express
> Edition      12.0.2000.8     No         Yes
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
> Server 2014    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014   Type:
> RTM   Version:                       12   SPLevel:
> 0   Installation location:
> f:\folder\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\setup\   Installation edition:
> Express
>
> Product Update Status:   User selected not to include product updates.
> Error message: The following is an exception stack listing the
> exceptions in outermost to innermost order Inner exceptions are being
> indented
>
> Exception type:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CancelException
> Message:
> Setup is not able to complete searching for updates because the operation was cancelled.
> HResult : 0x84b70642
> FacilityCode : 1207 (4b7)
> ErrorCode : 1602 (0642)
> Stack:
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchUtility.TrySearch(String
> serviceId, String query)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchEngine.Search(String
> serviceId, String query)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSetupSearchEngine.SearchUpdates()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.SearchUpdatesAction.ExecuteAction(String
> actionId)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String
> actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__b()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker
> workerDelegate)
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Install
> ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
> NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
> AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled   ASBACKUPDIR:
> Backup   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
> ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASDATADIR:
> Data   ASLOGDIR:                      Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:
> 1   ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL   ASSVCACCOUNT:
>    ASSVCPASSWORD:                    ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:               ASTEMPDIR:
> Temp   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic   CLTCTLRNAME:
>    CLTRESULTDIR:                     CLTSTARTUPTYPE:
> 0   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                    CLTSVCPASSWORD:
>    CLTWORKINGDIR:                 
> COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
> COMMFABRICPORT:                0   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
> CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:
>    CTLRSVCPASSWORD:                  CTLRUSERS:
>    ENABLERANU:                    true   ENU:
> true   ERRORREPORTING:                true   FEATURES:
> SQLENGINE, REPLICATION   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
> FILESTREAMSHARENAME:              FTSVCACCOUNT:
>    FTSVCPASSWORD:                    HELP:
> false   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true   INDICATEPROGRESS:
> false   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
> INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
> INSTANCEID:                    servername   INSTANCENAME:
> servername  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
> ISSVCPASSWORD:                    ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:
>    MATRIXNAME:                       NPENABLED:
> 0   PID:                           *****   QUIET:
> false   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   ROLE:
> AllFeatures_WithDefaults   RSINSTALLMODE:
> DefaultNativeMode   RSSHPINSTALLMODE:
> DefaultSharePointMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  
> RSSVCPASSWORD:                    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   SAPWD:                         *****   SECURITYMODE:
> SQL   SQLBACKUPDIR:                     SQLCOLLATION:
> Language_CI_AS   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$servername
> SQLSVCPASSWORD:                   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           domain\administrator
> SQLTEMPDBDIR:                     SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:
>    SQLUSERDBDIR:                     SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:
>    SQMREPORTING:                  true   TCPENABLED:
> 0   UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance   UpdateEnabled:
> false   UpdateSource:                  MU   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:
> false   X86:                           false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210627_113827\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Database Engine
> Services   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
> Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup
> process of the feature.   Next Step:                     Use the
> following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature,
> and then run the setup process again.   Component name:
> SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features   Component
> error code:          0x84BB0001   Error description:             A
> connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority
> that is not trusted.)   Error help link:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2269.0&EvtType=0xBA6E21AA%400x9A41B222&EvtType=0xBA6E21AA%400x9A41B222
>
> Feature:                       SQL Server Replication   Status:
> Failed: see logs for details   Reason for failure:            An error
> occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for
> the feature to fail.   Next Step:                     Use the
> following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature,
> and then run the setup process again.   Component name:
> SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features   Component
> error code:          0x84BB0001   Error description:             A
> connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority
> that is not trusted.)   Error help link:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2269.0&EvtType=0xBA6E21AA%400x9A41B222&EvtType=0xBA6E21AA%400x9A41B222
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\120\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20210627_113827\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

update:
opened the Sql Server installation Center,Maintenance .repair
most is green, the Database Engine Services failed:

> Action required: Use the following information to resolve the error,
> and then try the setup process again.
>
> Feature failure reason: An error occurred during the setup process of
> the feature.
>
> Error details: § Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services
> Instance Features The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not
> in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully
> configured. Only features from successful installations can be
> repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature. Error
> code: 0x84B40002 Visit
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2269.0&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402 to get help on troubleshooting.

update 2:
there is ESAT sql 2012 installed on the device. I don't see it running on port 1434 UDP.

update 3:
tried to install ms sql 2016

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is
> not trusted.)
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
> this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5026.0&EvtType=0xDC80C325
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### & Retry Cancel

when press retry the message is displayed again.
when clicking cancel, the installation finishes and :

> § Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance
> Features A connection was successfully established with the server,
> but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority
> that is not trusted.) Error code: 0x84BB0001 Visit
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5026.0&EvtType=0x6BB41ECB%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0x6BB41ECB%400xDC80C325 to get help on troubleshooting.

tried to install ms sql express 2008R2
failed :

> ### TITLE: SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
> Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority
> that is not trusted.)
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
> this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0&EvtType=0xBA6E21AA%25400x9A41B222
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### &Retry Cancel

sql 2014 cannot even start the install. has the error message:

> ### **TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position
> 268805.
>
> Error code 0x84B10001.
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0x066FCAFD%25400x5539C151
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: i cannot install MSSQL. how to install without this error

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall choosing to update the setup?
I saw this in the log above: "User selected not to include product updates"